# Is dynamic "Prefix-Soup" possible with Jolt

Tags: jolt

Given a simple document like this

```json
{
  "data": {
    "clientId": "prefix",
    "clientName": "Acme"
  }
}
```

and a spec like this

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "clientName": "bookMap.@(1,clientId)&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I expected output like this

```json
{
  "bookMap" : {
    "prefixclientName" : "Acme"
  }
}
```

Instead I get this

```json
{
  "bookMap" : {
    "prefix" : {
      "clientName" : "Acme"
    }
  }
}
```

Even though there's no dot `.` between the closing parenthesis of the @ notation and the &
is there a way to dynamically use an input value as a prefix in an output key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This spec should work for you:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "newKey": "=concat(@(1,clientId), clientName)"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "clientName": "bookMap.@(1,newKey)"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Tested with https://jolt-demo.appspot.com

You can find there also the [string concatenation example](https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#modify-stringFunctions)